# What does next build-in function mean in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyword, sublimetext3

So what does `next` keyword mean in python 3? I am using 3.4.0 and sublime 3 text editor and when I write `next` in it it turns blue? I tried to search about it but I haven't seem to find anything more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`next` is not a keyword but a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next).

The Python documentation also includes a [list of keywords](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords); you'll see it is not listed there.

In Python 2, iterators defined an [`iterator.next()` *method*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.next), but that has been renamed to [`iterator.__next__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.__next__) in Python 3. It is probably that method name the syntax highlighter tries to color-code; the [Python 3 package for Sublime Text](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Python%203) adds `__next__` as highlighted too.